# What is a "free object"?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Source: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method

I was wondering what the exact definition of a "free object" was in below context, and what free objects in general meant.

**Context**

Use the Factory Method when you want to save system resources by reusing existing objects instead of rebuilding them each time.

You often experience this need when dealing with large, resource-intensive objects such as database connections, file systems, and network resources.

Let’s think about what has to be done to reuse an existing object:

1. First, you need to create some storage to keep track of all of the created objects.
   When someone requests an object, the program should look for a **free object** inside that pool.
   … and then return it to the client code.
   If there are no **free objects,** the program should create a new one (and add it to the pool).
   That’s a lot of code! And it must all be put into a single place so that you don’t pollute the program with duplicate code.

Comment: Please do not language-spam.

Comment: A free one is one that hasn't left or has been returned to the pool, isn't held by any client.

Comment: While refactoring.guru is generally a good source for design-pattern related information, do note the GoF book says nothing about using a Factory Method as an object pool. This scenario may have been invented by the website author; and I would say there's no reason to confuse the Factory Method pattern with the [Object Pool](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool) pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free objects are objects of pool that was returned by user into pool or objects located inside pool.

What is pool?

As wiki says about [pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(computer_science)):

> In computer science, a pool is a collection of resources that are
> kept[clarification needed] ready to use, rather than acquired on use
> and released[clarification needed] afterwards. In this context,
> resources can refer to system resources such as file handles, which
> are external to a process, or internal resources such as objects. A
> pool client requests a resource from the pool and performs desired
> operations on the returned resource. When the client finishes its use
> of the resource, it is returned to the pool rather than released and
> lost.

You can see an example of [source code of `ObjectPool<T>` of .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Dependencies/PooledObjects/ObjectPool%601.cs) here